# YAML-based deployment not working from ADO, can do a manual deploy from VS Code

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am building a yaml-based release pipeline to deploy an app service from ADO to Azure App Services.  I can perform a manual deploy and all of the code deploys as a zip and then it works with WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE="1".

for example from VS Code:
az webapp config appsettings set --resource-group RGP --name sitename --settings WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE="1"

az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group RGP --name sitename --src sitename.zip

It returns

```
"author": "N/A",
  "author_email": "N/A",
  "complete": true,
  "deployer": "ZipDeploy",
  "end_time": "2022-02-02T04:28:38.6143958Z",
  "id": "xxx",
  "is_readonly": true,
  "is_temp": false,
  "last_success_end_time": "2022-02-02T04:28:38.6143958Z",
  "log_url": "https://sitename.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest/log",
  "message": "Created via a push deployment",
  "progress": "",
  "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
  "received_time": "2022-02-02T04:28:10.9806495Z",
  "site_name": "sitename",
  "start_time": "2022-02-02T04:28:11.3244119Z",
  "status": 4,
  "status_text": "",
  "url": "https://sitename.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest"
```

However, in my YAML release, I am using the following, and it both over-writes WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE="1" and won't run with or without that value added after the fact.  It return a site permission error.
Here is the relevant YAML section.  I'm wondering if I need to use deployer: zipDeploy somehow, based on the above success and the below failing even though it puts the same zip file in the wwwroot dir of the app service.  FYI - I am using terraform to provision the site and Configuration Items and then running the deploy afterwards.

```
    - stage: deploy
  dependsOn: [infrastructure]
  displayName: DEPLOY APP
  jobs:
    # Track deployments on the environment.
      - deployment: DeployWeb
        displayName: deploy Web App
        pool:
          vmImage: 'windows-latest'
        # Creates an environment if it doesn't exist.
        environment: '$(workstream)-$(env_identifier)'
        strategy:
          # Default deployment strategy
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
              - checkout: self 
              - bash: ls $BUILD_ARTIFACTSTAGINGDIRECTORY
              - bash: ls $PIPELINE_WORKSPACE
              - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
                displayName: 'deploy $(tier_prefix)-$(region_prefix)-$(workstream)-UI-01'
                inputs:
                  ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
                  azureSubscription: 'subname'
                  # SlotName: 'slot'
                  appType: 'webApp'
                  WebAppName: '$(tier_prefix)-$(region_prefix)-$(workstream)-UI-01'
                  ResourceGroupName: 'XZ$(region_prefix)-E-N-$(rgp_identifier)-$(tier_prefix)-RGP-10'
                  # DeployToSlotOrASEFlag: true
                  Package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/build/eu-web-$(workstream)/'
                  UseWebDeploy: true
                  enableCustomDeployment: true
                  deploymentMethod: runFromPackage
                  ExcludeFilesFromAppDataFlag: false
                  TakeAppOfflineFlag: false
                  removeAdditionalFilesFlag: true
                  additionalArguments: '-useCheckSum'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here was my solution, so far it seems to work.

I completely dropped everything around UseWebDeploy

```
              UseWebDeploy: true
              enableCustomDeployment: true
              deploymentMethod: runFromPackage
              ExcludeFilesFromAppDataFlag: false
              TakeAppOfflineFlag: false
              removeAdditionalFilesFlag: true
              additionalArguments: '-useCheckSum'
```

and change this

```
Package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/build/eu-web-$(workstream)/'
```

to this

```
Package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/build/eu-web-$(workstream)/eu-web-$(workstream)-$(env_identifier).zip'
```